# Front Page Settings

Tags: frontpage

I'm setting up a WordPress site that has Flash puzzles embedded in the pages. (My site will have pages instead of posts).

Each week I'll add a new puzzle to the site's Home page. When the site loads you'll see the newest puzzle. Older puzzles would be accessed through a dropdown menu.

My question is how should I design the permalink structure? Under Reading Settings, I plan to set the Front Page to static. And select the latest puzzle as the front page.

The problem is that if someone bookmarks the Home page, they'll get the latest puzzle.

Let's say this week's puzzle (on the Home page) is called "Astronomy". The path to the Home page would be, for example, www.mysite.com. Imagine that someone is a Carl Sagan nerd and wants to link to the Astronomy puzzle. After the week is over, a new puzzle would be on the front page. The "Astronomy" puzzle's path would now be www.mysite.com/astronomy and would be accessed through the dropdown menu.

Is there a way to avoid this problem? (Other than a blurb on the Home page with a link to the puzzle)?

Sorry, if this is an idiotic question. But, maybe someone has a good solution.

Thank you!

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you need pages over posts here. Using posts gives you ready made index home page, slugs and pretty permalinks give you link structure you want.

You can just add some blurb on home page that says "bookmark this puzzle" with direct permalink.

Comment: Yep; use Posts, not static Pages. A Static Page as Front Page is intended to be just that: *static*. You want your Front Page to be *chronological*, so the correct choice here is to use *Posts*. Simply set your site to display only one Post per page (Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading -> "Blog Pages Show At Most" -> Set to "1")